# How to add elements to an array from a background job

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to modify an array with background jobs. I launch several background job that add elements to an array, and listen to the length of array until it shows that all background job has finished adding that element.

I'm writing the following code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PROCS=( )

NAMES=( "a" "b" "c" "d" )

myfunc() {
  sleep 2
  PROCS+=( $1 )
}

for i in ${NAMES[*]}
do
  myfunc hello-$i &
done

while [ ${#PROCS[@]} -lt ${#NAMES[@]} ]
do
  echo "still waiting: ${PROCS[*]}"
  sleep 1
  done

echo ${PROCS[*]}
```

But it seems that the background job didn't actually add to the array. i.e. when it's running, it's stuck in the while loop forever.

I wonder what I did wrong with the code, and if I want to achieve this functionality stated above, what should I change with the code?

Comment: a 'background job' is actually a separate OS process with its own chunk of memory (ie, it does not share memory with any other OS process); in order to maintain a master array (eg, in the parent process) you will need to add some method of interprocess communications so that the child/background jobs can pass array entries (back) to the parent; a (very) simple idea for passing info (back) to the parent would be for each child/background job to write its data to an output file, then have the parent process each child's output file

Answer (score 0):

Using a file as a channel of communication :

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=/tmp/temporary_file
exec {fd}<>$temp
PROCS=( )

NAMES=( "a" "b" "c" "d" )

sleep=2
myfunc() {
  sleep $2
  echo $1 >> $temp
}

for i in ${NAMES[*]}
do
  myfunc hello-$i $sleep &
  sleep=$((sleep+2))
done

while [ ${#PROCS[@]} -lt ${#NAMES[@]} ]
do
  echo "still waiting: ${PROCS[*]}"
  read <&${fd}
  if  test "$REPLY"; then
      PROCS+=($REPLY)
  else
      sleep 1
  fi
done

echo ${PROCS[*]}
```

Comment: thanks! But when i tried running the script it shows `exec: {fd}: not found`. But when I just run this line in terminal, it works fine. Very confused since I declared that this is a bash script.

Comment: NVM, I just upgraded my bash and it works now. Thanks!